# How can I sum/subtract time values from same row

Tags: postgresql, time, sum, subtraction

I want to sum and subtract two or more timestamp columns.

I'm using PostgreSQL and I have a structure as you can see:
[image]

I can't round the minutes or seconds, so I'm trying to extract the `EPOCH` and doing the operation after, but I always get an error because the first `EXTRACT` recognizes the column, but when I put the second `EXTRACT` in the same SQL command I get an error message saying that the second column does not exist.

I'll give you an example:

```
SELECT 
    EXAMPLE.PERSON_ID,
    COALESCE(EXTRACT(EPOCH from EXAMPLE.LEFT_AT),0) +
    COALESCE(EXTRACT(EPOCH from EXAMPLE.ARRIVED_AT),0) AS CREDIT
FROM
    EXAMPLE
WHERE 
    EXAMPLE.PERSON_ID = 1;
```

In this example I would get an error like:

> Column ARRIVED_AT does not exist

Why is this happening?
Could I sum/subtract time values from same row?

Comment: Can you post actual structure of this table? From popular tool like psql or pgadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `ARRIVED_AT` a calculated value instead of a column? What did you run to get the query results image you posted showing those columns?

The following script does what you expect, so there's something about the structure of the table you're querying that **isn't** what you expect.

```
CREATE SCHEMA so46801016;
SET search_path=so46801016;
CREATE TABLE trips (
  person_id serial primary key,
  arrived_at time,
  left_at time
);

INSERT INTO trips (arrived_at, left_at) VALUES
  ('14:30'::time, '19:30'::time)
, ('11:27'::time, '20:00'::time)
;

SELECT
    t.person_id,
    COALESCE(EXTRACT(EPOCH from t.left_at),0) +
    COALESCE(EXTRACT(EPOCH from t.arrived_at),0) AS credit
FROM
    trips t;

DROP SCHEMA so46801016 CASCADE;
```